# How to submit my C# code in Code Forces? Getting runtime error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, runtime-error

This is my code and it works fine in VS 2022 but when I try to submit it in CodeForces, I get a runtime error.

How I can solve that ????

```
using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string? Val1 = Console.ReadLine(); 
        int Number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Val1);

        string? Val2 = Console.ReadLine(); 
        int Number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Val2);

        if (Number2 <= (Number1 + 1) / 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Number2 * 2 - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine((Number2 - (Number1 + 1) / 2) * 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error, and what are the `args` you are providing?

Comment: When I put my code in CodeForces, it writes this message "running time error" to me and I don't know what's wrong with the code

Answer (score 0):

```
     //if the test inputs in one line       
    var line = Console.ReadLine();
    var data = line.Split(' ');
    Number1  = int.Parse(data[0]);
    //first integer
    Number2  = int.Parse(data[1]); //second integer
```

Comment: It looks like you propose to use only one `Console.ReadLine()`, where both numbers are input separated by a space and then split it. Please clarify how this answers the question.